# Echo out all predefined constants of OpenSSL

Tags: php, openssl

Is it possible in PHP 5.x to echo out all [predefined constants](http://www.php.net/manual/en/openssl.constants.php) of OpenSSL e.g. through a loop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`get_defined_constants()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-constants.php) will return all defined constants, from which you can extract those with OpenSSL prefixes.

```
foreach (get_defined_constants() as $c => $val) {
  if (strpos($c, "OPENSSL_") === 0 || strpos($c, "PKCS7_") === 0 || strpos($c, "X509_") === 0) {
    echo $c . "\n";
  }
}
```